# How can I make drip use existing vm with dripmain.rb for rails app?

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails

I am attempting to use [drip](https://github.com/flatland/drip) to reduce JRuby VM startup time for a Rails app, per the [JRuby wiki](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Improving-startup-time#wiki-try-using-drip).

I see some speed up by changing some of the `JRUBY_OPTS` but I am not seeing any reduction using drip. It seems to be spinning up a new process/vm for each call instead of re-using the existing VM.

I was following [this guide](http://crashruby.com/2013/01/21/drip-with-jruby/) to get things setup.

#### dripmain.rb

```rb
require_relative './config/application'
```

#### terminal

```
$ { time ( jruby -e 'puts 9*9') }
81
( jruby -e 'puts 9*9'; )  0.08s user 0.08s system 14% cpu 1.144 total

$ drip ps
31166 org.flatland.drip.Main org.jruby.Main ...

$ { time ( jruby -e 'puts 9*9') }
81
( jruby -e 'puts 9*9'; )  0.08s user 0.08s system 13% cpu 1.182 total

$ drip ps
30965 org.flatland.drip.Main org.jruby.Main
```

I expected those process ids for drip to be the same. Open to hearing non-drip solutions as well. I looked into theine / nailgun but couldn't get them working either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was missing this export:

`export DRIP_INIT="" # Needs to be non-null for drip to use it at all!`

Solution found as part of [rvm shell script on github](https://github.com/justjake/teeveed/blob/master/drip.env.sh#L9).

```
# Source this file if you use Drip to make the JVM not suck
# drip: https://github.com/flatland/drip
# https://github.com/flatland/drip/wiki/JRuby

# JAVACMD is honored by jruby
export JAVACMD=`which drip`
# Drip preloads our codez
export DRIP_INIT_CLASS=org.jruby.main.DripMain
export DRIP_INIT="" # Needs to be non-null for drip to use it at all!

# settings from: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Improving-startup-time
export JRUBY_OPTS="-J-XX:+TieredCompilation -J-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -J-noverify -X-C"
```